# Convert Lat Long to X Y having lat/lon of corners of a map image

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, coordinates

I've map image (1816 x 8160) having following lat/lon of corners.

- TopLeft: (-73.9308,40.8883)
- TopRight: (-73.8584,40.858)
- BottomLeft: (-74.0665,40.7024)
- BottomRight: (-73.9944,40.6718)

Map is not true north and rotated at 28.34, also its UTM Zone 18N (78W to 72W). Here are further details about this map taken from PDF Maps iOS app.

```
Size (pixels): 1816 x 6160
Pixel Resolution: 3.829 meters
Bounds (pixels): (-1624, -3518) x (7866, 7719)
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32618"]]
```

How to convert lat/lon to x y and vice versa?
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```js
var dot_size = 15;
var longitude_shift = 0; //-28.34;   // number of pixels your map's prime meridian is off-center.
var x_pos = 0; //54;
var y_pos = 0; //19;
var map_width = 1380; //1816; //430;
var map_height = 4682; //6160; //332;
var half_dot = Math.floor(dot_size / 2);
// Converts from degrees to radians.
Math.radians = function(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}; 
// Converts from radians to degrees.
Math.degrees = function(radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
};

/* N 40.88839 -73.93071 //-73.9308
E 40.85789 -73.85843  //40.858 -73.8584
W 40.70228 -74.06652 //40.7024 -74.0665
S 40.67185 -73.99437 //40.6718 -73.9944 */
var bottomX = 40.67185;
var bottomY = -73.99437;
var topX = 40.88839; //-73.9308; //-73.9308,40.8883
var topY = -73.93071;

var degreesPerPixelX = (bottomX - topX) / map_width; //0.07225 / map_width;
var degreesPerPixelY =  (bottomY - topY) / map_height; //0.18605/ map_height; 

// These should roughly box Germany - use the actual values appropriate to your image
var minLat = bottomX;
var minLong = bottomY;
var maxLat = topX;
var maxLong = topY;

// Map image size (in points)
var mapSize = {'width': map_width, 'height': map_height};

// Determine the map scale (points per degree)
var xScale = mapSize.width / (maxLong - minLong);
var yScale = mapSize.height / (maxLat - minLat);

var south = Math.radians(40.67185); //lat 47.2
var north = Math.radians(40.88839); //lat 55.2
var west = Math.radians(-74.06652); //long 5.8
var east = Math.radians(-73.85843); //long 15.2

// Formula for mercator projection y coordinate:
function mercY(lat) { return Math.log(Math.tan(lat/2 + Math.PI/4)); }

// Some constants to relate chosen area to screen coordinates
var ymin = mercY(south);
var ymax = mercY(north);
var xFactor = mapSize.width/(east - west);
var yFactor = mapSize.height/(ymax - ymin);

var mapLonLeft = -74.06652; //9.8;
var mapLonRight = -73.85843; //10.2;
var mapLonDelta = mapLonRight - mapLonLeft;

mapLatBottom = 40.67185; //53.45;
mapLatBottomRadian = mapLatBottom * Math.PI / 180;

function convertGeoToPixel(lat, lon)
{
    pX = (lon - mapLonLeft) * (mapSize.width / mapLonDelta);
    lat1 = lat * Math.PI / 180;
    worldMapWidth = ((mapSize.width / mapLonDelta) * 360) / (2 * Math.PI);
    mapOffsetY = (worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(mapLatBottomRadian)) / (1 - Math.sin(mapLatBottomRadian))));
    pY = mapSize.height - ((worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(lat1)) / (1 - Math.sin(lat1)))) - mapOffsetY);

    return 'x:'+pX+', y:'+pY;
}
function convertPixelToGeo(tx, ty)
{   
    /* called worldMapWidth in Raphael's Code, but I think that's the radius since it's the map width or circumference divided by 2*PI  */   
    var worldMapRadius = mapSize.width / mapLonDelta * 360/(2 * Math.PI);     
    var mapOffsetY = ( worldMapRadius / 2 * Math.log( (1 + Math.sin(mapLatBottomRadian) ) / (1 - Math.sin(mapLatBottomRadian))  ));
    var equatorY = mapSize.height + mapOffsetY;   
    var a = (equatorY-ty)/worldMapRadius;

    var lat = 180/Math.PI * (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(a)) - Math.PI/2);
    var long = mapLonLeft+tx/mapSize.width*mapLonDelta;
    return 'lat:'+lat+', lng:'+long;
}
function draw_point(x, y) {
    dot = '<div style="position:absolute;width:' + dot_size + 'px;height:' + dot_size + 'px;top:' + y + 'px;left:' + x + 'px;background:#00ff00"></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += dot;
}
function plot_point(lat, lng) {
 spotLat = lat;
 spotLong = lng;
    // Mercator projection
    // longitude: just scale and shift
    x = (map_width * (180 + lng) / 360) % map_width + longitude_shift;

    // latitude: using the Mercator projection
    lat1 = lat * Math.PI / 180;  // convert from degrees to radians
    y = Math.log(Math.tan((lat1/2) + (Math.PI/4)));  // do the Mercator projection (w/ equator of 2pi units)
    y = (map_height / 2) - (map_width * y / (2 * Math.PI)) + y_pos;   // fit it to our map

    x -= x_pos;
    y -= y_pos;
 
 // position of map image for point
 //var newXY = 'x:' (spotLong - minLong) * xScale + ', y:' + (spotLat - minLat) * yScale +'<br/>';
 //var y = (spotLat - minLat) * yScale;
 
 //alert('x: ' + kavraX(Math.radians(lat),Math.radians(lng)) + ', y: ' + kavraY(Math.radians(lat),Math.radians(lng)));
 
 strText = 'kavra x:' + kavraX(Math.radians(lat),Math.radians(lng)) + ', y:' + kavraY(Math.radians(lat),Math.radians(lng)) + '<br/>';
 strText += 'x:' + x + ', y:' + y + '<br/>';
 strText += 'x:'+(spotLong - minLong) * xScale +', y:' + (spotLat - minLat) * yScale +'<br/>';
 strText += 'x:'+((Math.radians(lng) - west)*xFactor)+' ,y:'+((ymax - mercY(Math.radians(lat)))*yFactor)+'<br/>';
 strText += convertGeoToPixel(lat,lng)+'<br/>' ;
 //floatingDiv = '<div style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;">'+strText+'</div>';
 //document.body.innerHTML += floatingDiv;
 $('#leftDiv').html(strText);
    draw_point(x - half_dot, y - half_dot);
}
function kavraX (latitude, longitude) // Kavra for Kavrayskiy 
// formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavrayskiy_VII_projection
{
  return ((3 * longitude) / 2 * Math.PI)*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.PI, 2)/3 - Math.pow(latitude, 2));
} 
function kavraY (latitude, longitude) 
{
  return latitude*-1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
//-73.949321, 40.796997
plot_point(40.764296, -73.973027);
  $('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
 var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
 var clickedLon = topX + relativeX * degreesPerPixelX;
    var clickedLat = bottomY + relativeY * degreesPerPixelY;
 alert(relativeX+':'+relativeY+' lat:'+clickedLat+", lon:"+clickedLon);
  });
  
  $('#parentDiv').mousemove(function(e) {
    var offset = $('img').offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
 var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
 var clickedLat = topX + relativeX * degreesPerPixelX;
    var clickedLon = topY + relativeY * degreesPerPixelY;
 //alert(relativeX+':'+relativeY+' lat:'+clickedLat+", lon:"+clickedLon);
 var strText = relativeX+':'+relativeY+' lat:'+clickedLat+", lon:"+clickedLon+'<br/>';
 strText += 'lat:'+(relativeY / yScale + minLat)+', long:'+(relativeX / xScale + minLong)+'<br/>';
 strText += convertPixelToGeo(relativeX,relativeY)+'<br/>';
 //floatingDiv = '<div style="position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;">'+strText+'</div>';
 //document.body.innerHTML += floatingDiv;
 $('#rightDiv').html(strText);
  });
});

/*$(function() {
$("#test").click(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
  alert(relativeX+':'+relativeY);
  $(".position").val("afaf");
});
});*/
   

function onClick (evt) {
 alert(evt.pageX +' '+ evt.pageY);
    var x = getEventOffsetFromImageLeft(evt);
    var y = getEventOffsetFromImageTop(evt);

    var clickedLon = topX + x * degreesPerPixelX;
    var clickedLat = bottomY + y * degreesPerPixelY;
}
</script>
</head>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<!-- onload="plot_point(40.756, -73.986)" -->
<body >
<div id='parentDiv'>
 <!-- image found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXgSw.jpg -->
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXgSw.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px" >
 <div id="leftDiv" style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;"></div>
 <div id="rightDiv" style="position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849854/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-x-and-y-coordinates

Comment: I tried and its giving x: -11.036900291825647, y: -0.012414987560827094 for 40.756, -73.986?

Comment: Run Code Snippet added you can try yourself. Remember source image resolution is changed by i.stack.imggur so map img width/height will change.
'var map_width = 1380; //1816;
var map_height = 4682; //6160; '

Comment: In code snippet above you can see I tried different approaches but none giving me exact results. Anyone can try and compare result with google maps or other maps applications.

Comment: It looks like results are not correct because my map is rotated 28.34. Anyone have thought on how to get x, y from lat,long (and vice versa) on rotated map?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/178354/115

Comment: Re-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853937/convert-lat-lng-to-pixel#comment57817373_34853937